# Xamarin PCL Unhandled Exception: TargetInvocationException

Tags: soap, xamarin.ios, xamarin, dynamics-ax-2012, xamarin.forms

Im making an mobile application which can communicate with Dynamics AX using a WCF service.

Im fairly new to Xamarin, and im trying to create a PCL library for a shared IOS and Android application. Im also working on an Windows Phone App which pretty much works by now. Im using a WCF service ive created which does all the communication with Dynamics AX, and the service exposes its methods using Metadata. I've added a Service Reference to the Windows Phone solution and the generated Proxy works like a charm, i should say im using SOAP.

But if i transfer the generated Reference.cs file to my Xamarin PCL project and call my method the exact same way i get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Expected element 'ExceptionDetail' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel', but found Element node 'AifFault' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Fault'
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterDeserializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Type declaredType, System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeCollection knownTypes, IDataContractSurrogate surrogate, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver resolver, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver defaultResolver, System.String name, System.String ns, Boolean verifyObjectName) [0x0003e] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/7.4.0.108/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization/XmlFormatterDeserializer.cs:63 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) [0x00024] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/7.4.0.108/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization/DataContractSerializer.cs:363 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader reader) [0x00000] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/7.4.0.108/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization/XmlObjectSerializer.cs:76 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0019b] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/7.4.0.108/src/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:550 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00038] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/7.4.0.108/src/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:496 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0001c] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/7.4.0.108/src/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:477 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The issue only occurs when AX return an AIFFault Exception and for some reason it cant be caught by Xamarin.. Its caught just fine in Visual Studio in Windows Phone.

Here is the code from making the call:

```
try{
     var result = await _service.ExecuteGetMethod(MyRecord)
}
catch(FaultException fe){
     ShowError(fe);
}
```

This works just fine, and the error message from AX is showed in fe.Message, but running the exact same in Xamarin gives me the above error.

Do i need to add AIFFault somewhere in my WCF service for clients to be able to see it?